# Still can't delete tableviewcells

Tags: swift, uitableview, nsindexpath, uitableviewrowaction

I posted about this at the start of the month but nobody responded and I tried to alter it myself as days went by but after reading like 20 posts and trying to implement code from each post, I'm still stumped.

All I want do is successfully delete a cell in my app with no error.

[image: Error]

This is the error I keep getting when trying to delete a cell, I've read it a million times, and tried to change up my code so many times, but I can't take it anymore.

Here is my code:

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, for orientation: SwipeActionsOrientation) -> [SwipeAction]? {
     guard orientation == .right else { return nil }

 let deleteAction = SwipeAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { action, indexPath in
  

    let documentId = self.documentsID[indexPath.row]!.docID
    
    self.db.document("school_users/\(self.user?.uid)/events/\(documentId)").delete { (err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error deleting the docs")
        } else {
            print("Docs successfully deleted.")
        }
    }
    
    self.documentsID.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)

    
 }
    
     deleteAction.image = UIImage(named: "delete-icon")

     return [deleteAction]
 }
```

This function deletes the document out of the database which is great, but it also completely crashes my app, I've tried wrapping things in `DispatchQueue.main` closures, `DispatchQueue.global` closures and to all no avail. Yes this is an embarrassing question to ask but I just want to figure it out once and not have to worry about it again.

I will also attach my `numberOfRowsInSection` method since the error mentions that as well.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    
    if events.count > 0 {
        tableView.separatorStyle = .singleLine
        tableView.separatorColor = .systemGreen
        tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 25, bottom: 0, right: 25)
        return events.count
    } else {
        tableView.separatorStyle = .none
        return 0
    }
    
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That error message is basically saying "You had 12 rows initially and you deleted 1 (with the `deleteRows` method`), but now are saying you still need 12 rows, so something's not right".

So in your case, event.count must still be generating the number 12. Did you make sure to delete an element from `events` before calling the `deleteRows` method?

Comment: Yeah I've tried that one and it still crashes. I just can't understand why it's so hard to figure out. @Eric33187

Comment: Shoot. Well if you print(events.count), what number does it produce? It should be 11 (in your example case)

Comment: That was a screenshot from an older post, I have 3 cells currently so I will try it again and see what it prints. @Eric33187

Comment: Yeah it prints 2 then crashes. @Eric33187

Comment: Yeah I mean that seems very odd, because that warning is saying after the deletion, you should be returning n-1 rows, but apparently it's saying you aren't.. Maybe there's a way to check how many rows you have just before the deletion, and right after. I would just keep narrowing it down and make sure everything makes sense as you would expect, because there seems to be a hidden problem somewhere that you aren't noticing.